# pick arbitrary unmasked element from numpy masked array

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

I have 3-D masked array of dtype=uint8, and I want to do something like `arr.max(axis=-1)`, but instead of always picking the max, i want to either (1) find first (or last) unmased element, (2) pick random arbitrary unmasked element or (3) pick median or mode along axis, like `numpy.ma.median` or  `scipy.stats.mstats.mode`

The approach (3) is what I would like in ideal world, but it is extremely slow.  i then tried finding max, which runs quick.  but i dont want always use max value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if computational speed is an issue with `ma.median`, you might consider using the corresponding 'normal' numpy function on just the unmasked part of the array:

```
arr = ma.array(some_array)
med = ma.median(arr)                # masked array solution
med = np.median(arr.compressed())   # 'normal' function on unmasked part of arr
```

Apart from the compression part, this shouldn't be any slower than normal.

*Update* I just checked the speeds of the two methods: the 'normal' function using the compressed array is 5-15 times as fast as the masked array solution, depending on the fraction of masked elements ... :-)